# ¿"Hater" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, jerga-internet

En la jerga de internet, es muy común usar el anglicismo "hater":

> Últimamente Twitter está lleno de **haters**: cada vez que alguien
>   publica algo sobre el partido X, lo critican sin misericordia.

"Hater" se traduce como *persona que odia*, pero la connotación es de un odio ligero, muy visceral pero circunscrito al ámbito de lo escrito, sin llegar a la violencia: Alguien puede ser un hater de un lenguaje de programación, un jugador de fútbol o vete a saber qué.

Me pregunto si hay alguna palabra en castellana que quiera decir lo mismo. Se me ocurrió decir *odioso*, porque los haters lo son, pero esto se referiría a lo que se odia, y no a la persona.

Y ya que estamos, ¿cómo traduciríais "*haters gonna hate*"? ¿"Los que odian van a odiar"?

[image]

Comment: "Odión". Si esta palabra no existe, la acabo de crear.

Comment: Vaya, algún _hater_ votó negativamente mi pregunta y todas las respuestas. Verificado: existen tales personas : )

Comment: La pregunta me parece bien planteada, aunque recomiendo que quites la imagen, que a mi aviso no ayuda en la presentación.

Comment: @aparente esta imagen es famosa en SE pues solía salir en una pantalla de error, de esas 404. Además, nótese que consulto por cómo traducir _haters gomna hate_, que es lo que dice esta imagen. Por cierto, diríamos _a mi modo de ver_.

Comment: @fedorqui - Gracias por explicar el significado de la imagen para tí.  (No tengo la menor idea por qué SE la escogió para su página de 404....)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No creo que haya un sinónimo *exacto* (como casi con todo) pero se me ocurren varias traducciones para escoger, dependiendo del contexto. No sé si entiendo bien lo del panda: ¿se refiere a "disfruta, aunque siempre hay alguien a quien le va a caer mal" o "ya verás como incluso esto le cae mal a alguien"?

- Un buen término sería "atrabiliario", que suele aplicarse a la crítica, pero que es de poco uso en la lengua cotidiana. Se podría decir "sus comentarios sobre este tema son atrabiliarios". Para usarlo en el ejemplo que das no funciona muy bien.
- Criticón: la traducción podría ser "los criticones lo van a criticar" o "los criticones critican" o incluso "siempre va a haber criticones que critiquen".
- Aguafiestas: "los aguafiestas te aguarán (o intentarán aguarte) la fiesta".
- Colérico: "los coléricos se encolerizarán".
- Sañudo: no es un término muy de uso informal pero se puede decir "lo sañudos se ensañarán".
- Rabioso: "los rabiosos se enrabiarán".

Comment: +1 por _criticón_, me parece la opción más acertada de las que propones, y [recogida por la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BKMzwE5): _Muy dado a la crítica y la censura._

Comment: Buscando por Ngram los usos de _criticón_, encontré en la revista _Politica: Quince días de México y del mundo_ esta frase: _"El criticón es al crítico lo que el estrábico o el daltoniano a una persona de vista normal y clara."_ Por proponer una adaptación de _haters gonna hate_ que sea corta, yo diría **_siempre habrá criticones_**.

Comment: La imagen del panda a mí me sugiere que hagas lo que hagas, alguien te criticará. Por tanto, relájate y disfruta.

Comment: +1 Excelente respuesta y [Bienvenido a Spanish Language Stack Exchange](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Parece que es un termino que con el sentido usado en esta frase ha sido acuñado recientemente y en el contexto de Internet. Viene a ser el antónimo de seguidor o fan. En ese sentido no creo que exista una traducción acertada. Quizá los contrarios a...

Comment: +1 Yo colocaria la de Criticón de primero. Pero eso me haría un Criticón?

Answer (score 5):

En efecto no es fácil encontrar una traducción exacta para `hater` pero yo me inclinaría más por `odiador` que por cualquier otra traducción, basado en el concepto que tiene esta frase en el lo que a internet respecta, la cual se podría definir como aquella persona que tiene un odio natural y casi que infundado por algún tipo de acciones, ideas, publicaciones etc, burlándose, denigrando o difamando de ellas. A mi siempre me ha sonado la frase:

> Los odiadores van a odiar.

que sería como: Para aquellas personas que se suelen disgustar de este tipo de actos van a efervescer en sus ánimos.

Aunque no me suena mal y suena acertada:

> Los odiosos van a odiar.

Answer (score 5):

[**"Detractor"**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spanish/detractor) también es un sinónimo válido. Oxford dictionaries lo define como:

> *adjetivo/nombre masculino y femenino*
>
> [persona] Que critica a una persona o cosa o manifiesta un juicio
>   peyorativo por no estar de acuerdo con ella. Ejemplo:
>
> *sus detractores apuntan que todas sus películas son como los anuncios de perfumes caros de bastante duración; proseguían ayer los debates
>   entre los partidarios y detractores de uno u otro plan económico.*

Answer (score 5):

Soy de los Estados Unidos (lo siento por la gramática).

"Haters gonna hate" es más una declaración de los que no son "haters" acerca de la persona a quien atribuye el título "Hater". Es como decir que la persona que escoja odiar no odia por una razón válida, sino que es una persona que odia solo porque quiere odiar.

Quiere decir que no tiene sentido discutir con la persona que odia, sino que es mejor pasar por alto o desatenderlo.

Es parecido a 'a boca de borracho, oídos de cantinero'.

Answer (score 1):

Tu traducción es bien acertada.
En realidad es un sustantivo que no es fácil darle la connotación sustantival al español.

Esto también aplica a varias formas como *lovers gonna love, players gonna play,* etc.
Aunque la diferencia de estos es que sí podemos entregar una forma sustantival correcta.

Buscando en WordReference, muestran a *hater* como *alguien* que odia *algo* o *a alguien*, por lo que es acertado escribir *los que odian van a odiar.*

Answer (score 1):

1. Hater del lenguaje de programación Fantasma, del jugador de fútbol Fulano, del partido Fantasma, etc., por ejemplo *Phantasm hater, Joe Smith hater*:

   **anti-Fantasma virulento, anti-Fulano virulento**

   Tu frase:

   > Últimamente Twitter está lleno de **anti-X virulentos**: cada vez que alguien publica algo sobre el partido X, lo critican sin misericordia.

   Si prefieres algo menos compacto:

   > Últimamente Twitter está lleno de **gente virulentamente anti-X** etc.
2. "Haters gonna hate": Primero hay que tener claro el significado y uso de esta frase.  Voy a suponer que quieres usar esta frase como se ilustra en [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](http://Farlex%20Dictionary%20of%20Idioms):

   > *slang* There will always be those who criticize anything and everything. The phrase is often used to dismiss such critics while acknowledging that it is no use trying to stop them. *I don't enjoy when opposing teams' fans boo me, but, hey, haters gonna hate.*

   **Los odiatodo odian todo.**

   Inspirado por el "sábelotodo".  [Uso ilustrado](http://www.el-nacional.com/noticias/columnista/los-sabelotodo_209367):

   > En realidad, los sabelotodo son personas que están seguras de que sus opiniones son correctas, ello en virtud de que ellos mismos son la fuente. Los sabelotodo solo están interesados en sí mismos y solo le prestan atención a segundos o terceros en la medida que estos apoyan su imagen de “estar en lo correcto”.

   Para pronunciar la frase hay que dejar una pequeñita pausa:

   > Los odiatodo ... odian todo.

   Otro ejemplo, tomado no no me acuerdo cuál diccionario (creo Collins):

   > *The guy is just a hater, looking for a fight.* | Es un odiotodo.  Nomás busca pleito. [No le hagas caso.]

Answer (score 0):

Además de `odioso`, como ya han sugerido muchos, me inclino a ir más allá de la traducción literal. Parece que no hay una traducción exacta al español, lo que me invita a introducir algo de filosofía aquí. Quien odia no puede ser feliz, por lo que yo utilizaría

> Amargado/a

que es, según mi parecer, quien realmente se comporta como describe el término. Al hacerlo así encontramos, de hecho, muchas más palabras relacionadas:

```
quejoso, quejicas, resentidos/as, heridos/as, etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

"Odión", o "Odiador". Si estas palabras no existen, se pueden crear. Si bastantes personas adoptan el uso de una palabra nueva, se aceptan.

Answer (score -1):

*Hater* para mí es como decirle a alguien:

> Eres una odiosa.

Como también sería:

> Eres una presumida.

O algo así como: **odiosa**, **fachosa**, **presumida**.