# ¿Es posible que palabras iniciadas con "bi" o "pre" no tengan un prefijo?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, etimología, prefijos

### Español:

Palabras como **premio** no parecen ser un "mio" que "llega antes", como lo indicaría un prefijo como "pre".

Lo mismo ocurre con **biblioteca** que no parece ser una "blioteca" "dos veces", como lo indicaría el prefijo "bi".

Por lo tanto me pregunto si habrá casos de palabras como estas parecen indicar. Es decir, ¿hay más palabras que comiencen con un "prefijo" quizás por su origen etimológico y no por la normativa de ser un prefijo que ha alterado el significado de la palabra raíz?

### English:

Words like **Premio** has the prefix "pre" but don't seem to follow its meaning.  *Premio* is not a ´mio´that is ´before´

Same goes for  **Biblioteca** which although has the prefix "bi" does not refer to 2 ´bliotecas´

Am I correct in assuming that neither of these cases are actually using prefixes?
This makes me wonder, if that is the case, How can I distinguish between words that are actually using a ´prefijo´ and others that don't?

Comment: @木林森: En el caso de "praemium", sí, [es un prefijo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praemium): prae (antes) + emo (obtener). En el caso de biblioteca, el raíz es "biblio", que es greco para "libro".

Comment: @Flimzy totalmente de acuerdo con premio. Sin embargo con biblioteca, yo consideraría biblio- como raíz y -teca como sufijo.

Comment: ¿No es ningún requisito de esta web que no haya faltas de ortografía?

Comment: @guillem: Con razón. Gracias.

Comment: @Jdamian no, no es ningún requisito. Piensa que hay mucha gente cuya lengua materna no es el español, y que aun así se expresan en español haciendo un esfuerzo. Esos esfuerzos hay que valorarlos y agradecerlos, [y no criticarlos](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17159/hater-en-castellano). De hecho, es tarea de los usuarios con más experiencia el pulir las preguntas si ves que la redacción se puede mejorar, siempre (por supuesto) sin alterar el significado original de la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Te refieres específicamente a los prefijos *bi-* (dos) y *pre-* (antes)? Porque llevado al extremo cualquier raíz podría ser considerada un prefijo. Con pre-, existen precario, presión, premura, prender, precio entre otros que vienen de raíces indoeuropeas distintas. Con bi- están la biología, todos los bio-, biblio- y aparentemente *bilis*.

Comment: Como decía Marcos Mundstock al fallecido Daniel Rabinovich en _El negro quiere bailar_: ["Y esto (digo) deja de ser un simple monólogo para convertirse en un bi-ólogo"](http://www.lesluthiers.org/verversion.php?ID=121).

Answer (score 4):

As in most -if not all- languages, the existence of a prefix -even if very common- does not rule out the existence of words with the same beginning that do not come from the same root. It may be seen as just a coincidence. It may (or may not) be an example of convergent evolution of words of diverse origin through sound change, a late (or old) borrowing from another language, just similar roots with a common beginning, or even something else.

Among words starting with *pre-* that do not include the meaning of the prefix *before* (either in its current or ethymological meaning), one may list:

> **precario**, **preces**, **prender**, **premura**, **presión**, **presura**, **precio** and **precioso**

Examples of words starting with *bi-*, but without the *two* meaning:

> **bilis**, **bisonte**, **Bizancio**, **biología** and **bibliografía**

(as well as derivates and lots of words starting with *bio-* and *biblio-*)

Note that in English the same principle applies: both prefixes do exist, and some of the words listed have cognates with alike structures. Particularly, **bison** (Spanish *bisonte*) comes from Germanic and got into Spanish through middle English.

---

(**Note**: The same can be said of suffixes: while *-mente* usualy forms adverbs, you have *mente* -a noun- and *demente* -an adjective-. In English *-ly* forms adverbs, but you have the nouns *belly*, *lily* and the adjectives *lonely*, *lovely*. See also [this](http://blog.writeathome.com/index.php/2014/03/non-adverbs-that-end-in-ly/).)