# Translation-golf VIII: with a twist

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés, rima

Vamos a darle un poco de emoción al asunto. Ya que en la anterior edición se propuso una traducción con rima, vamos a seguir por el mismo camino pero dándole un poco de vidilla.

El siguiente texto es un poema de los muchos que salen en *El señor de los anillos*:

> All that is gold does not glitter,
>       Not all those who wander are lost;
>   The old that is strong does not wither,
>       Deep roots are not reached by the frost.
>   From the ashes a fire shall be woken,
>       A light from the shadows shall spring;
>   Renewed shall be blade that was broken,
>       The crownless again shall be king.
>
> <sub>(237 caracteres)</sub>

Este poema es una descripción de Trancos y una predicción de los eventos que se narran posteriormente. En español el poema se hizo tristemente famoso entre los traductores como ejemplo de mala traducción, ya que el traductor se dejó llevar por la frase hecha en el primer verso, y lo tradujo así:

> No es oro todo lo que reluce.

Con lo cual el sentido del poema se pierde, al ser Trancos precisamente un trozo de oro que no brilla (pasa desapercibido a pesar de su linaje). Corrigiendo ese primer verso, la traducción de la edición española queda así (221 caracteres):

> No todo lo que es oro reluce,
>  ni toda la gente errante anda perdida;
>  a las raíces profundas no llega la escarcha;
>  el viejo vigoroso no se marchita.
>  De las cenizas subirá un fuego,
>  y una luz asomará en las sombras;
>  el descoronado será de nuevo rey,
>  forjarán otra vez la espada rota.

La traducción española pierde el ritmo y la mayor parte de la rima, que se queda en una rima asonante en los versos pares. También alterna el orden de algunos versos (el 3 y el 4 y el 7 y el 8): podéis recurrir a trucos similares siempre dentro de un límite, que será no alterar la posición de un verso más de una posición arriba o abajo.

¿Y dónde está el giro inesperado de guion? Pues que esta vez vamos a meter un **bonus por respetar la rima**, que como se ve es A-B-A-B-C-D-C-D. Se considerarán los siguientes bonus:

- 5% de descuento en el total de caracteres si se consigue una rima asonante con la misma estructura de rima.
- 10% de descuento en el total de caracteres si se consigue una rima consonante con la misma estructura de rima.

No será necesario respetar el ritmo. En caso de decimales, se redondeará siempre hacia arriba. Ejemplos:

- 100 caracteres sin rima: sin bonus.
- 105 caracteres con rima asonante: 105 * 0,95 = 100 (99,75).
- 110 caracteres con rima consonante: 110 * 0,90 = 99.

Ganaría pues la versión con rima consonante. En caso de empate entre versiones, la rima consonante gana a la asonante, y esta al caso sin rima.

Recuerda seguir [las normas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/12637), y como siempre, ¡la traducción fiel [con menos caracteres](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/) gana!

---

¡Fin de la partida! El ganador es [walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21061/12637), quien con su traducción ha noqueado al resto de contrincantes. Mención especial a [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21051/12637), que ha intentado reponerse a última hora.

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted?  I'm not saying it should or shouldn't have, just that it would be nice if the downvoter left a comment.

Comment: Yo hubiera votado +1 varias veces si podría. Un verdadero virguería que merece ser accesible en cualquier idioma.

Comment: ¡Me gusta este requiebro de la rima! Y no os preocupéis por los votos negativos... [_los criticones critican_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17159/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui pues si te gusta ya sabes, ¡esperamos tu aportación! :-)

Comment: @walen tu entrada esperamos // con gran impaciencia // no dejes llevarte // por vana indolencia.

Comment: Curiosamente, la traducción de la versión española gira el orden de un par de versos: _a las raíces profundas no llega la escarcha_ se pone en la línea 3.ª en lugar de las 4.ª original y lo mismo con _forjarán otra vez la espada rota_ que pasa de la 8.ª a la 7.ª. ¿Hay _legislación_ al respecto en este juego? :)

Comment: @fedorqui mientras se traduzcan todos los versos, alternar el orden de algunos me es indiferente siempre que sea una cosa cabal: el tercer verso por el cuarto y cosas así está bien, pero no me vayas a poner el primer verso el último. :-) (Incluyo esto en las normas.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 161 caracteres

145 con bonus.
Rima consonante A-B-A-B-C-D-C-D.
Métrica 8-8-10-10-8-8-8-8 (me habría gustado que fueran dos cuartetas, pero... buf).

> No todo el oro ha fulgor,
> Ni perdídose quien vaga;
> Viejo duro no cede vigor,
> Hielo la honda raíz no llaga.
> De brasa, fuego avivado,
> De sombra, brota destello;
> Hierro de nuevo forjado,
> Rey otra vez el plebeyo.

Notas:

- *Ha fulgor*: verbo "haber" usado en 1ª del presente como sinónimo de "poseer" ([5ª acepción](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Jv4Frsm)); igual que en expresiones como "ha lugar", "ha menester" y otras reconocidas por la RAE.
- *Ni perdídose*: "ni se ha perdido" pero reutilizando el "ha" del verso anterior en elipsis como, ahora sí, el auxiliar "haber" ;)
- *quien vaga*: 1ª del presente de "[vagar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=bFsrlQS)".
- *Viejo duro*: "duro" como sinónimo de "fuerte" ([3ª acepción](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=duro)).
- *llaga*: 1ª del presente del verbo "[llagar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=llagar)". Entendiendo que cuando el hielo alcanza una raíz, lo que hace es dañarla, causarle herida.
- *De brasa*: uso "brasa" en lugar de "ceniza" porque tiene más sentido (si se reaviva el fuego, alguna brasa habría!!); y porque me hace falta para mantener la métrica y la figura estilística con el siguiente verso.
- *brota*: traducción literal de *spring*.
- *Hierro*: como sinónimo de "espada" y, en general, de cualquier arma hecha de hierro o acero ([7ª acepción](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=hierro)). Sería fácil cambiarlo por "hoja" y ajustar género y rima, pero me mola usar "hierro" así.
- *de nuevo forjado*: se sobreentiende que si vuelven a forjarlo es porque estaba roto :)
- *plebeyo*: estirando un poco el significado, lo uso para referirme al "sin corona"; pequeñísima licencia para que me cuadren métrica y rima, aunque creo que se entiende bastante bien.

Comment: Una propuesta sencillamente alucinante. Lo he flipado en colores mientras la leía. Solo tengo una duda: ¿se considera la rima "destello/plebeyo" consonante? Lo pregunto porque ahí me has pillado...

Comment: Preguntado está lo de la rima consonante, a ver qué nos dicen.

Comment: ¡Eres el ganador! Si nos quieres deleitar con un nuevo juego, tienes dos días para plantearlo.

Comment: Ahora entiendo lo de "ha lugar". ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>197, 189</s> 176 caracteres

¡Conseguí rima consonante!

> No todo oro reluce,
>    ni todo errante está perdido;
>   raíz honda aún produce,
>    viejo fuerte no se ha ido.
>   De las cenizas resurge la llama,
>    de las sombras una luz brota;
>   A los depuestos su reino reclama,
>    renovada será la hoja rota.

- Tal y como hace la versión española expuesta en la pregunta, giro los versos 3.º y 4.º, así como los 7.º y 8.º. Así me resulta más fácil mantener la rima consonante.

El diccionario de sinónimos y antónimos saca humo.

- *No todo lo que es oro reluce* es muy descriptivo, por lo que una simplificación del tipo *No todo oro reluce* la considero equivalente en cuanto a mantener su significado.
- En lugar de mencionar que el viejo *no* se apaga, prefiero (es decir, me da menos letras) usar que está vivo.
- [*Entumecer*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FqMVp4j) puede verse como la consecuencia de recibir mucho frío. Por tanto, la expongo como traducción a *reached by the frost*.
- Honda por profunda, pues [hondo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Kcm8214) es lo *que tiene profundidad*.

Comment: ¡Gran entrada! A ver, te comento: en la primera mitad hay rima asonante en los versos 2 y 4, pero no la hay en 1 y 3, por lo que no hay bonus. Acepto tus variantes menos la de "los depuestos pueden volver al juego", ya que el original habla tanto de rey como de corona, cosas que no se entienden con tu versión. Consejos: si no te sale nada con "-ego" cambia "fuego" por "llama" o por algún otro sinónimo que te facilite ese séptimo verso.

Comment: Sí, la falta de rima consonante entre 1 y 3 es lo que me hizo poner _casi manteniendo..._. Seguiré investigando. Me apunto lo del rey, a ver si sale algo moviendo versos, palabras o lo que sea.

Comment: Me sentí un poco Sergio Dalma con sus rimas _bailar es bailar_ :) Nada, cambio _llama_ de llamar por _reclama_. Como voy pillado de tiempo no prometo mejoras.

Comment: @walen ¡cierto! Mi rima consonante / es impresionante ;-) Uy, sin haberlo pensado / me ha salido un pareado... ¡otro!

Comment: Si quieres apurar puedes cambiar "desde las sombras" por "de las sombras" (o incluso "del oscuro"), "la hoja tras ser rota" simplemente por "la hoja rota"...

Answer (score 2):

#### 186 caracteres

> Hay oro que no resplandece
>   y errantes no perdidos;
>   El viejo duro no desvanece,
>   radicales hondos por hielo no son obtenidos.
>   De las cenizas prenderá flama,
>   una luz del oscuro saltará
>   nuevo será la rota pala
>   El rey echado regresará.

#### 190

> Hay oro que luz no arroja
>   y errantes no perdidos;
>   El viejo duro no se [aja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ONL70Cw),
>   radicales hondos por hielo no son conseguidos.
>   de las cenizas arderán la flama,
>   una luz del oscuro saltará
>   nueva será la rota [catana](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7uTdupk%7C7uU3R7l)
>
> El rey destronado regresará.

Comment: Una aproximación muy buena, pero necesitarás hacer algunas correcciones: el cuarto verso no tiene sentido en español (debería ser "raíces hondas por hielo no son alcanzadas", pero claro, pierdes la rima); en el tercer verso deberías explicar el uso de "reduce" al traducir "wither"; y en el último verso "el rey echado" me suena a que se ha echado al suelo, aunque no me puedo quejar dado que se puede entender como "el rey que fue echado" (tal vez pudieras cambiarlo por "el rey destronado" o algo similar, que sonaría mucho mejor).

Comment: También deberías corregir la rima de los últimos cuatro versos: debería ser C-D-C-D pero tú tienes C-C-D-C, por lo que no puedo darte el bonus.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ahora?

Comment: Me gusta "desvanece", pero el cuarto verso sigue sin tener sentido. El problema no era "raíces", eso estaba bien. El problema era "por hielo no son obtenidos". Deberías cambiar el verbo "obtenidos" por "alcanzados" u otro similar. Y no puedo aceptar la traducción de "sword" por "palo", lo siento.

Comment: Muy bueno el uso de "aja", pero como es un verbo transitivo deberías usarlo como pronominal: "no se aja".

Comment: y la rima es imprecisa

Answer (score 2):

No puedo evitar responder a mi pregunta. Oculto la respuesta para no condicionaros y os aclaro que, por supuesto, **no participa en esta edición**, pero es que el poema me encanta...

> No todo lo que es oro brilla,
>  ni todo el errante [vaguea](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bGPvAo5);
>  el hielo a la honda raíz no pilla,
>  el anciano fuerte aún [verdea](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bbtLpQm).
>  De las cenizas subirá una llamarada,
>  las sombran verán la luz brotar;
>  la espada rota será reforjada,
>  el rey sin trono volverá a reinar.

No me convence la rima de los versos 1 y 3, me suena muy infantil, pero no se me ocurría otra cosa.

**201 * 0,90 = 181 caracteres**

Answer (score 2):

**237 caracteres (214 con el bonus):**

> A veces el oro de brillo carece,
>   No siempre extraviado quien vaga se encuentra.
>   Lo viejo, si fuerte, no se desvanece;
>   En raíz profunda la escarcha no entra.
>
> De cenizas llama surgirá, avivada;
>   La luz de las sombras nacer se verá;
>   La hoja que fue rota será restaurada,
>   Aquel sin corona a reinar volverá.

Diría que "the old" no se refiere a un viejo, sino a lo viejo (o a "los viejos" en conjunto); de lo contrario, sería "the old man", "he who is old", o algo por el estilo.

Comment: ¡Más vale tarde que nunca! :-) ¡Gracias por participar aunque sea [a toro pasado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a6ZyZYZ#DFKJfy8)!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Es verdad, me había olvidado de ponerlo en término pero, como me rompí bastante la cabeza, quise mostrarlo de todos modos.