# ¿Cuándo se considera una rima consonante?

Tags: poesía, rima

En la actual edición del [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) se ha propuesto [la rima "destello/plebeyo"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21061/12637) como consonante. A mí me parece consonante, y según la Wikipedia basta con que los fonemas sean los mismos desde la vocal acentuada.

Sin embargo, nos hemos quedado con la duda, al no ser la Wikipedia una fuente oficial. ¿Lleva la RAE estos temas? Si no, ¿qué fuente oficial nos puede confirmar cuándo una rima se puede considerar consonante? ¿Sería válida la propuesta?

Comment: A mí me enseñaron que la 'll' y la 'y' no suenan igual, luego sería rima asonante... Aunque soy consciente de que muy poca gente hace esa distinción...

Comment: @MikMik Depende de la región: en muchos sitios la pronunciación de ambas letras es la misma. Tienes más información en _[How to pronounce the consonants “y” and “ll”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3/12637)_

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Gracias. Soy consciente de que en muchos sitios la pronunciación es la misma. De ahí el "muy poca gente hace esa distinción". Para empezar, yo mismo... En fin, la pregunta habla de si hay que tener en cuenta la escritura o la pronunciación (gana esta última). Y, en el caso de 'll' e 'y', al igual que 'c', 's', 'z' y otros casos, depende de cómo se pronuncien esas letras... Vamos, que si usas la rima "destello/plebeyo" en un soneto en clase de lengua, algunos profesores la darán por buena y otros no...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De momento, lo más oficial que he encontrado es la propia definición que da el DRAE para **consonante**:

> [**consonante**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=consonante)
>   2. adj. Dicho de la rima: Basada en la identidad de los **sonidos** vocálicos y consonánticos a partir de la última vocal acentuada en dos o más versos. *U. t. c. s. m.*

Donde se especifica que la rima se basa en los sonidos, no en las letras.

Enlazo también a la entrada de la Wikipedia para [rima consonante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima_consonante), donde al final se incluye el siguiente ejemplo de rima consonante fonética, sacado de un poema del poeta chileno Carlos Pezoa:

> *A los que sueñan renombre y gloria*
>   *y hacen su almuerzo con un pequén*
>   *¡Pueda que suela causarles risa'*
>   *esta romántica longaniza*
>   *digna del estro de Paul Verlaine*
>
> En este caso, riman *risa* con *longaniza*, ya que en América la "s" y la "z" tienen el mismo sonido. También, riman *pequén* y *Verlaine*, ya que la pronunciación castellanizada de este apellido es `/berlén/`.

Comment: "Risa"/"longaniza" y "destello"/"plebeyo"... ¿no llamaban a eso **rima dialéctica** cuando dependía del dialecto?

Comment: @jdamian sería *rima **consonante** dialéctica* ya que hay variedades del español con un sistema vocálico de 3 que podrían hacer rimas *asonantes* dialécticas, pero el término tal cual, *rima dialéctica* no se usa (si lo buscas en Google, solo salen para mí menos de diez resultados)

Comment: Más me parecería *rima dialectal*, ya que *dialéctica* significa otra cosa. Tampoco esta forma tiene uso (tres resultados en Google, dos de ellos iguales), pero me parece interesante.

Comment: En mi opinión, la definición de rima consonante no admite mucha duda (la de la RAE que copia la respuesta creo que se acepta generalmente). Esa rima de Pezoa o la del ejemplo que aparece en la pregunta me parecen defensas de la validez de una pronunciación dialectal y su valor está en esa defensa.