# Translation Golf XIV - 200 note

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, rima, italiano

¡Tenemos nuevo ganador!
[blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21768/13628) en su primera participación ha conseguido la traducción más corta. ¡Enhorabuena!

Como en anteriores partidas, el ganador tiene dos días para elegir el texto de la siguiente edición y crear la pregunta correspondiente. Pasado ese plazo, cualquier usuario podrá hacerlo :)

---

¡Nueva edición de [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf)!

Las reglas dicen que el texto original puede estar en cualquier idioma, pero hasta ahora todos los textos han sido en inglés. ¿Qué os parece si probamos un idioma nuevo? :D

A continuación presento un fragmento de una canción en italiano:

> *Ed è così che va la vita e il suo percorso
>
>   In equilibrio tra il rimpianto ed il rimorso
>
>   E restiamo a curare I nostri pezzi di cuore
>
>   Che siamo il sangue che scorre e che inventa l’amore
>
>   Il passato è passato e non c’è niente da fare
>
>   Lo puoi perdere o lo puoi cercare
>
>   In queste notti così vuote
>
>   E nella camera 200 note*
>
> <sub>(249 caracteres)</sub>

Son innumerables las canciones en italiano que han sido traducidas al español a lo largo de los años, con mayor o menor fortuna. A pesar de ser idiomas bastante parecidos, las restricciones de métrica y rima hace que muchas veces la letra en español cambie un poco el sentido del original. Por ejemplo, la letra oficial de la versión en español de esta misma canción:

> Y por ahí se van la vida y su camino
>  en equilibrio entre el lamento y el tormento
>  y tú y yo remendamos un corazón que se ha roto
>  que somos sangre que fluye y que vive de amores
>  el pasado es pasado y no se puede hacer nada
>  o lo pierdes o no lo buscabas
>  los sonidos ahora flotan
>  y a nuestro alrededor 200 notas.
>
>  <sub>(243 caracteres)</sub>

Quien entienda italiano*, podrá ver que ***esta no es una traducción fiel al original*** y, por tanto, no valdría como respuesta para este juego ;)
<sub>* Quien no, [aquí tiene una traducción al ingles](https://pastebin.com/XuZbhZpD).</sub>

¿Os veis capaces de crear una letra mejor? Y para quien se atreva con la rima...

**¡BONUS!**: aplican los bonus por rima propuestos en [la edición VIII del juego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21045/translation-golf-viii-with-a-twist):

- 5% de descuento en el total de caracteres si se consigue una rima asonante con la misma estructura de rima.
- 10% de descuento en el total de caracteres si se consigue una rima consonante con la misma estructura de rima.

***Andiamo!***

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: Qué _currada_ está esta pregunta del _translation-golf_! Muy bien formateada, bien redactada, aporta algo nuevo y no descuida ningún aspecto para que todo el mundo pueda participar. Buen trabajo!

Comment: Bueno, yo copié también de la anterior, creo que creo que era de @Diego. Así que el 25% del mérito va para él... :-D

Comment: Esto empieza a parecerse a una lista doblemente enlazada (o a algún tipo de referencia circular peligrosa...) yo creo que copié ese formato de Carlos, jajaja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### <strike>214 208 202 190  184</strike> 182 caracteres (164 con bonus por rima <strike>asonante</strike> consonante)

> Así es la vida y su estela
> entre culpa y pesar se nivela
> nuestro roto corazón sanea
> la sangre corre y amor crea
> el pasado pasó y nada procede
> o se pierde o buscarse puede
> en estas noches sin sustancia
> y 200 notas en la estancia

No he respetado la métrica original pero he intentado mantener cierta coherencia en mis versos. <strike>No he conseguido más que una rima asonante.</strike>

**Actualización**

- el camino de la vida lo hace la propia vida, por eso creo que puedo decir *estela* manteniendo el significado.
- <strike>Cambio *viaje* por *vía*.</strike>
- <strike>En lugar de *se debate* utilizo *armonía* como sinónimo de equilibrio.</strike>
- **Sanear:** Reparar o remediar algo.
- Cambio *trozos de corazón* por *roto corazón*.
- <strike>Le robo a Carlos Alejo la palabra *pasión* en lugar de *amor*.</strike>
- <strike>Reduzco la frase *el pasado ha pasado* con pasado el pasado* y cambio *quedo atrás* por * hay que hacer*.</strike>
- **Proceder:** Continuar en la ejecución de algunas cosas que piden tracto sucesivo.
- <strike>Cambio el orden de *buscar* y *perder* para mantener la rima.</strike>

Comment: Coincido con @walen, muy buenos los dos últimos versos, aunque el resto tampoco está mal.

Comment: @walen Sí, lo de *quedó atrás* es más flojo pero de momento no se me ocurre nada mejor. Cuando he dicho una rima consonante me refería a los últimos versos no a la rima de toda la canción pero está bien tu edición también.

Comment: @walen No había caído en que la frase continuaba en el siguiente  verso, en ese caso si que cambia. También creo que con *culpa y pesar en armonía*  me he pasado, es muy distinto a lo que decía la frase original

Comment: Puedes quedarte con "pasión", yo he vuelto a "amor". :-) A ver si @walen me aprueba la reducción.

Comment: Nueva versión. A ver si @walen me la da por buena y sigo en la lucha.

Comment: @walen vale, vuelvo a procede

Comment: Mi idea con *no cede* era que el tiempo no perdona, cuando ha pasado nada puede cambiarse

Comment: Eso se lo he copiado a Carlos, que puso lo de ofusca. Lo dejo como antes que todavía tengo una mínima ventaja.

Comment: Ok. Me convence tu explicación ;)

Comment: Gracias @walen, ha sido divertido! Buscaré algo para el nuevo translation golf.

Answer (score 3):

¡Uoh, un translation-golf en italiano! ¡Me encanta! ¡Me lo apunto para la próxima!

#### <strike>233 223 197</strike> 186 caracteres (168 con bonus de rima consonante)

> Y así va la vida y su andanza:
>   dolor y pesar en la balanza,
>   corazones rotos que debemos sanar,
>   la sangre fluye para el amor crear.
>   El pasado, sin remedio, se va, se ofusca,
>   o se pierde o se busca
>   en estas noches tan rotas,
>   y en la sala 200 notas.

**Concesiones:**

- "Andanza": Acción de recorrer diversos lugares considerada como azarosa.
- Cambio "equilibrio" por <strike>"estable"</strike> "balanza".
- <strike>Uso de *pasión* (inclinación o preferencia muy vivas de alguien a otra persona) en vez de *amor*.</strike>
- <strike>Altero el orden de perder y buscar, no sé si eso alterará el significado de los dos últimos versos.</strike>
- Al reducir el sexto verso me quedó buscar una palabra que acabara en "-usca", espero que introducir "ofusca" para indicar que el pasado poco a poco queda atrás y se difumina no rompa la traducción.
- <strike>Los dos últimos versos, curiosamente, son los que me están dando más guerra. No consigo rimarlos coherentemente, y al final he tirado por *remotas*, lo que me va a valer la descalificación, dado que no traduce el sentido de *vacías* más que de refilón (algo remoto puede dar la sensación de algo solitario, como en "una aldea remota"). Tengo que buscar alguna alternativa.</strike> Una vez conocido el contexto, la rima más simple creo que es la más efectiva. Las noches están vacías porque le falta alguien que ya no está, así que creo que se puede decir que las noches se le han roto.

Comment: @walen pues no sé, como no conozco el contexto me sonaba mejor "una". Lo cambio y a ver si saco un rato para repasar ese final.

Comment: En vez de *remotas* he pensado *ignotas* pero estamos en las mismas. ¿O quizás usando un calzador podríamos decir vacío = sin rumbo? Y usando *rota* en vez de *rumbo*: *en estas noches sin rota*. Aunque es una letra más

Comment: @blonfu de hecho, al final he puesto "noches tan rotas", apelando a que las noches se le han deshecho a la cantante.

Comment: Así suena más natural,  ¡Buena jugada!

Comment: @walen Hoy se me ha hecho tarde pero mañana le doy una vuelta a ver si saco algo. No tengo ni idea de italiano así que tendré que fiarme de los traductores online y lo que ha hecho ya Carlos

Comment: @walen pues hale, pongo "estable" que es más corto que "en equilibrio", a ver si así consigo pasar el corte. :-)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo no creo que pueda superar esta nueva versión. Yo también quise meter balanza  pero no encontraba una rima. Veré que puedo hacer para mejorar mi propuesta ¿cuando acaba la competición?

Comment: @blonfu en una semana desde que se hizo la pregunta, tienes tiempo.

Comment: @walen pues por una reducción sencilla, creo que aún tengo margen de maniobra. :-)