# Translation-golf XXI - Death or Glory

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

The Clash es uno de los grupos más importantes del movimiento punk y el álbum *London Calling* el más representativo de la banda en el cual se definirá su estilo musical (soul, rockabilly, ska, reggae...).

Hoy os traigo un fragmento de una canción de este disco: ***Death or Glory*** que es una declaración de intenciones y una defensa del grupo que algunos acusaban de venderse tras firmar con la CBS.

> Now every cheap hood strikes a bargain with the world
> Ends up making payments on a sofa or a girl
> Love 'n hate tattooed across the knuckles of his hands
> Hands that slap his kids around, 'cause they don't understand how
>
> Death or glory, becomes just another story
> Death or glory, becomes just another story
>
> 'n every gimmick hungry yob digging gold from rock 'n roll
> Grabs the mike to tell us he'll die before he's sold
> But I believe in this and it's been tested by research
> He, who fucks nuns, will later join the church
>
> <sub>(409 caracteres)</sub>

Esta versión en castellano (no es una traducción literal) pertenece al disco-homenaje *«por algo mas que por gusto»* de *La Furia*, grupo creado únicamente para este proyecto:

> Otro día más diez horas en el taller
>  media vida en extras pa llegar a fin de mes
>  amor y odio tatuado en los nudillos de las manos
>  golpeas a tus hijos por si no se han enterado de que
>
>  Muerte o gloria, ya ves, esta es nuestra historia
>  Gloria o muerte, y tú ¿cual sera tu suerte?
>
>  Y la estrella de turno que del Rock & Roll se enriqueció
>  aún viene con el cuento de que nunca se vendió
>  pero es lo que yo pienso, y es cosa bien segura
>  el que folla con monjas acaba siendo cura
>
>  <sub>(365 caracteres)</sub>

**¡BONUS!**:

Igual que en otras [ediciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21045/translation-golf-viii-with-a-twist) con canciones o poemas aplican los bonus por rima:

- 5% de descuento en el total de caracteres si se consigue una rima asonante con la misma estructura de rima.
- 10% de descuento en el total de caracteres si se consigue una rima consonante con la misma estructura de rima.

Pongamos que la rima es AABB  CCDD para simplificar dejando fuera el estribillo.

Aceptaré la rima del cuarto verso como en el original, antes de *how*, o al final de la frase.

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/this-is-translation-golf-the-translation-with-the-least-number-of-characters-wi/2592#2592)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

---

¡Enhorabuena @walen! Eres el vencedor de esta edición del translation golf, no ha tenido mucha participación pero era una traducción complicada, bien jugado. Tienes dos días para proponer un nuevo juego.

Comment: Un texto interesante, pero convendría que comentaras cuál es la estructura de rima del original, porque no me queda clara.

Comment: Es cierto que leyéndolo no queda claro, ecuchando la canción  por la forma en que pronuncia las palabras se entiende mejor: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Td6I5l9UnSg AABB en las dos estrofas, edito y lo añado.

Comment: Tarde, es que desde la app móvil no se ve si una pregunta es CW o no...

Comment: @walen la traducción la pongo porque lo piden las reglas para dejar claro que no se necesita y es solo un juego. La cosa es usar el original y no la versión en español.

Comment: No, si yo quiero usar el original, pero espero que la primera frase me la pueda aclarar el Urban Dictionary, porque así a bote pronto...

Comment: La verdad que es una frase complicada y he visto varias traducciones de la canción  sin pies ni cabeza. Yo he encontrado un sentido a la frase que creo que es el más lógico: por un lado tenemos "cheap hood", no he visto ninguna traducción pero lo he encontrado en varios textos y creo que sé lo que es y por otro lado la expresión "strikes a bargain". Espero que eso arroje un poco de luz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### <s>264</s> 217 (<s>238</s> 196 con bonus)

> Todo bribón se lo monta ya,
>   a plazos compra chicas, sofá;
>   tatúan sus puños: "odio", "amor";
>   pega a sus críos, pues no ven valor en
>
> "Muerte, gloria... da igual."
>
> Del rock todo pícaro enriquecido
>   dice al micro "Antes muerto que vendido"
>   mas lo creo, es ciencia pura:
>   folla monjas y serás cura.

Comment: ¿Lo de *a una letra por segundo* como lo explicas exactamente? No veo la relación con el original. Por lo demás nada que objetar. Me ha sorprendido que exista la palabra *aurívoro*.

Comment: Ah vale, no había pensado en letras de cambio. Aceptado.

Comment: Como he comentado en la traducción de @Charlie no acabo de ver claro lo de los tatuajes, en mi opinión ni sé entiende bien que lleva esas palabras tatuadas. Tampoco me convence "Del rock todo pícaro codicioso", en esa frase no dice que se ha enriquecido con el rock, me gustaba más la versión anterior.

Comment: ¿El verso intermedio no debería llevar una rima entre "glory" y "story"?

Comment: @Charlie, Dejé fuera esa rima al poner la estructura y aunque quedaría mejor mantenerla no me parece bien cambiar de criterio ahora que casi ha terminado el juego

Comment: @blonfu vale, no había visto que esa rima no era necesaria. Retiro lo dicho.

Answer (score 3):

### <strike>292</strike> 248 - 10% bonus rima consonante = 224 caracteres

> Hay andrajosos petándolo,
>   con putas, y el sofá pagándolo,
>   "Odio", "amor": nudillos tatuados,
>   sus hijos, ignorantes, maltratados.
>
> Muerte o gloria, es solo otra historia.
>
> Con el rock se forran malotes de risa.
>   "Muerto antes que vendido", su micro nos avisa.
>   En esto creo, ha sido probado:
>   los follamonjas, curas han acabado.

Explicaciones:

- Al empezar con "hay" hablo del presente, no es necesario poner cosas como "y ahora" o "ya".
- Entiendo que los dos primeros versos hablan de que cualquiera puede "cerrar un trato con el mundo", lo que interpreto como que puede tener éxito entre las masas, de ahí que use "[petarlo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sp9s0La)" en su acepción actual evolucionada de "estallar, explotar", que es "tener éxito de forma repentina (y tal vez inesperada)".
- Entiendo además que si el tío paga lo mismo un sofá que una tía, entiendo que se refiere a una prostituta.
- Evito la repetición del verso central por entender que no añade nada al juego. Lo importante es respetar la mini-rima del propio verso.
- Se puede decir "[rock](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WZmFUm8)" simplemente como sinónimo de "[rocanrol](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WZCUBH6)".
- "[Forrarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IGjpRdP)" es "enriquecerse".
- Entiendo que un "yob" es, según he visto definido, "lo contrario de lo que un buen chico debería ser". Por eso uso una versión despectiva del adjetivo "malo" usando el sufijo "[-ote](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RKJVS8I)", que forma despectivos a partir de adjetivos.
- Al decir que el malote era "de risa", cancelo la interpretación de "malote" como "tipo duro" al decir que se le veía tan falso que daba risa.
- "[Micro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PBMwTFa)" se puede usar como contracción de "micrófono".
- El término "follamonjas" es un compuesto de dos palabras que sí aparecen en el DLE.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que no queda clara la razón de porque pega a los niños. Aparte creo es que no se entiende muy bien ni en esta traducción ni en la de @walen que lleva tatuado "amor" y "odio" en los nudillos.